# is it possible to save contacts on windows phone 8 emulator permanently in phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8-emulator

Hi i'm unable to save the contacts in my windows phone 8 emulator permanently.contacts are saving just for a temporary period in people app.when i open that emulator and save contacts in it. They are getting saved but when i close that emulator and again reopened..no any contacts are showing in that people app .I want to import that contacts in my app for sending some info.but i cant proceed as its not showing any contacts in it.I gone through phonegap tutorial tried this code also.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
    function onDeviceReady() {

    var contact = navigator.contacts.create();
    contact.displayName = "xyz";            
    var name = new ContactName();
    name.givenName = "abc";
    contact.name = name;
    contact.save(onSaveSuccess,onSaveError);
function onSaveSuccess(contact) {
    alert("Save Success");
}


function onSaveError(contactError) {
    alert("Error = " + contactError.code);
}
```

Comment: This is just the way the windows phone emulator works. Data does not persist between runs of the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you can't do that because WP8 API doesn't allow that. You only have Read-only access to Contact API.

See the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207071%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

EDIT: After reading a little more about your issues I found [this one](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.5.0/cordova_contacts_contacts.md.html#contacts.create). So I think that your problem is with emulator only, that doesn't persist data after turned off.

Comment: is there any solution for this..?if i want to import this contacts then what should i try..?